# What is the meaning of ideals of the form $I_1(XY)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

We take the polynomial ring $\mathbb{K}[x_i,y_j]$ where $\{x_i\mid 1 \le i \le m\} $ and $\{y_j\mid 1 \le j \le m+1 \}$.
We consider $X$ is a Vandermonde matrix where the entries come from $\langle \{x_i\mid 1 \le i \le m \}\rangle$ and $Y$ as a $ m+1 \times 1$ matrix.

Then the ideal generated by $I_1(XY)$ is the ideal generated by the $1 \times 1$ minors or the entries of the $m \times 1$ matrix $XY$.

What does this ideal $I_1$ mean is essentially my doubt? As $X$ is an $m \times m+1$ matrix and $Y$ is an $ m+1 \times 1$ matrix. Is it possible to show with an example?

Comment: Please provide some context: where does this come from? Is $X$ the Vandermonde matrix with rows or columns $(1,x_i,x_i^2,\dots,x_i^m)$? Is $Y$ just any column vector or the column vector $(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{m+1})^t$?